# Data normalization by using mean and standard deviation - Strange example

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, inference, standard-deviation, normalization

I read a paper which talks about two samples; the first one concerning data (e.g. resistance $R_{ct}$) from a biosensor1 (called module), the second one concerning data from biosensor2 (called CHI).

The author compares these data in a way which is difficult to grasp for me. In particular he said (from paper "Sun 2016 IEEE - A Multi-Technique Reconfigurable Electrochemical Biosensor"):

"The results, shown in Fig. 8, show the mean and standard deviation of the measurements normalized to the CHI data."

[image]

Could you explain me the normalization procedure please? Why did he calculate $\frac{\mu_{biosensor1}}{\mu_{CHI}}$ and $\frac{\sigma_{biosensor1}}{\mu_{CHI}}$?

Comment: Let's look on the bright side: the author realised that starting the bars at 97 was a much better idea than starting at 0. How did this get published? Why won't people show the data too? Why does a bar appeal in any sense? The means and SD bars aren't enhanced in any way by the thicker bars.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the authors are not 'normalizing' to prepare a statistical elaboration, but just to show the results of their elaboration. Using their words: "While the variance in the data from the module is larger than that of the benchtop potentiostat ([...] $0.630\Omega$ versus $0.186\Omega$) each is still within acceptable bounds for that particular technique and matches well with the CHI measurements", i.e. the module measurements are very close to the CHI measurements: more than $99.5\%$ on average, within about $99\%$ and $100.3\%$.
Here 'normalizing' means "using CHI average measurement as a benchmark."
The figure is not perfect, but... what is the problem?

I'm not an engineer, so let me play with toy numbers.
The average CHI measurement is $50$, its confidence interval is $(49,51)$.
The average module measurement is lower, $49.2$, its confidence interval is wider, $(48.2,51.2)$, because of a larger variance.
Dividing by $50$, i.e. using $50$ as a benchmark, you have:

- CHI: $100\%$ on average, in $(98\%,102\%)$;
- module: $98.4\%$ on average, in $(96.4\%,102.4\%)$.

CHI is more precise, but module is still acceptable.

Comment: Hello Sergio I noticed that the author calculated $(CHI \, mean / CHI \, mean)=1=100 \%$ and $(module \, mean / CHI \, mean)$...so maybe he normalized only the means, but not the standard deviations

Comment: They normalized the confidence interval bounds (which depend on the standard deviation).